# Juicebox Gallery - Full Screen by Default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, gallery

I am using Juicebox Gallery (https://www.juicebox.net) in my Drupal site as a module. It's working out great. There are three buttons at the top of the gallery - one of which toggles full screen. Is there a way I can make this gallery full screen on page load? Or, instead, open to full screen after clicking another button on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question!
Add "#expanded" at the end of the URL. Easy enough. :)